# 3D printer calibration test STLs?

Tags: 3d-models, calibration

Is there any well-known test set of 3D models that I can print out which will clearly show up the problems I need to work out in calibrating my 3D printer? Ideally, it would be either one or multiple models which shows the point at which overhanging starts to fail, points at which stringing occurs, the accuracy of one layer over another, and maybe edges which are supposed to be a particular length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

There are more test models one can download than would be possible to list here. A search on Thingiverse results in pages and pages of useful models. A common model for testing is called the 3d Benchy, although it is not particularly parametric. Overhangs, retraction, layer alignment and other aspects of your printer are tested with this model.

Another option is to purchase a set of test models from 3dkitbash.com:

[QuickPrintTests](http://www.3dkitbash.com/quick-prints/)

The models lists as such:

```
#3dk01 - Voids
#3dk02 - Spikes
#3dk03 - Flex
#3dk04 - Edge
#3dk05 - Text
#3dk06 - Bridge
#3dk07 - Dissolve
#3dk08 - Ball Joint
#3dk09 - Hinge
#3dk10 - Columns
```

which are more specifically defined for testing your printer. I would expect that Thingiverse and other model-sharing sites would have similar designs available to meet your specific requirements.

Comment: The QuickPrintTests is fantastic, and is exactly what I'm looking for but isn't free.

Comment: The 3dkitbash people are in the business of selling their creative work. Considering how challenging it is to make models, especially organic models such as their creatures and "puppets," it's not too much of a surprise that they would charge for the calibration modules. You may be able to find similar models on the model sharing sites, and you have a good reference with their list.

Comment: I've found this free test build that also includes the specific tests accomplished:

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1363023